# Understanding methods Vs functions in scala

Tags: scala

I am learning the difference between methods and functions. I am following this link

http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html

The article says if you compile the following code:

```
class test {
def m1(x:Int) = x+3
val f1 = (x:Int) => x+3
}
```

We should get two files
1. test.class
2. test$$anonfun$1.class

But I do not get it. Secondly the example says if we execute the following command in REPL, we will get the below

```
scala> val f1 = (x:Int) => x+3
f1: (Int) => Int = <function>
```

But I get only this

```
scala> val f1 = (x:Int) => x+3
f1: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1549/1290654769@6d5254f3
```

Is it because we are using a different version? Please help.

Comment: Yes, earlier versions of Scala (and REPL) will produce the `<function1>` representation of the result.

Comment: You should *never* rely on implementation details like this. For example, for obvious reasons, Scala.js will generate ecactly *zero* class files, always.

Answer (score 2):

Scala 2.11 and earlier versions behave as shown in the blog post.

The behavior changed in Scala 2.12. Scala now uses the lambda support that was added to version 8 of the JVM, so it doesn't need to emit the extra `.class` file. As a result, the `.jar` files produced by 2.12 are usually a lot smaller.

As a side effect of this, Scala can't override `toString` anymore, so you see the standard JVM `toString` output for lambdas.